# How would I use sed to detect a certain amount of numbers before it inserts a character? ###-###-####

Tags: bash, command-line, sed

I need to format phone numbers in a text file. They appear as (example) `8014516912`

How would I format it so that I can insert a `-` after the first 3 numbers, and then another `-` after another 3 numbers, so it would appear as `801-451-6912`

How would I do this for all lines that contain a phone number? Keep in mind that the phone numbers are between text, so the numbers aren't always at the same index. For example it can be like:

```
atewfnwieug 8204919561
adw 8915617141
```

Answer (score 6):

You need numerical quantifiers for this:

```
sed -r 's/\b([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})\b/\1-\2-\3/' your_file
```

The `-r` switch, which enables extended regular expressions, is not POSIX though, so a more portable solution would be

```
perl -pe 's/\b([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})\b/$1-$2-$3/' your_file
```

In extended regular expressions, the quantifier `{n,m}` means match the previous atom at least `n` times and at most `m` times. For example, the quantifier `?` can be expressed as `{0,1}`. Omitting `m` means no upper limit: `+` can be written as `{1,}`. Finally, `{n}` means match the previous atom exactly `n` times.

If you want to use `sed`, you don't exactly need to have extended regular expressions for this; it's just that the basic regular expressions form would be less readable:

```
sed 's/\b\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\b/\1-\2-\3/' your_file
```

Comment: Things change over the years, I'm using sed 4.7 and --help shows: `-E, -r, --regexp-extended use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX -E).`

Comment: If I have varying number of numbers, like 2 or 3 before the first dash (instead of 3 fixed), how to do this?

Comment: I would like to use \1 in my match, but use extended regex, like {} without escaping, how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use perl for this instead:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\b(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})\b/$1-$2-$3/' foo.txt 
atewfnwieug 820-491-9561

adw 891-561-7141
```

You can also do it in place, `sed`-like:

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe 's/\b(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/$1-$2-$3\b/' foo.txt
```

If your phone numbers can be adjacent to letters like this:

```
abcd1234567890abc
abcd1234567890
1234567890abc
```

you can use this one instead:

```
$ perl -pe 's/([^\d]*)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})([^\d]*)/$1$2-$3-$4$5/' foo.txt 
abcd123-456-7890abc
abcd123-456-7890
123-456-7890abc
```

All these choices assume that phone numbers are always 10 digits long as in your example.